# I used a android project exported by unity to test App Asset Bundles, how can i customize my asset pack path?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My project structure like this

[image]

The file was provided by Google said: the assset pack must be put in the root dir,and I dont kown my project has something wrong ,the test result was : cant not find the asset pack floder.And this is the currect test project,the structure like this

[image]

so ,how can I get a right aab from my project structure?